# Ошибка в библиотеке PIL: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textsize'

Tags: python-3.x, pil

Есть код:

```
reply_text = message.reply_to_message.text
# Создаем изображение с текстом
image = Image.new('RGB', (500, 500), (255, 255, 255))
image_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size=50)
text_width, text_height = ImageFont.textsize(reply_text, font=font)
text_x = (500 - text_width) // 2
text_y = (500 - text_height) // 2
image_draw.text((text_x, text_y), reply_text, font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
```

При выполнении данного кода выдается ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textsize'
```

Что надо поставить вместо ImageFont? Пробовал ImageDraw, результат тот же

Comment: Ошибка не в библиотеке (ага, тысячи людей без проблем пользуются, а ты такой хоп, и ошибку нашел!), а в твоем коде. Пчему ты думаешь, что у ImageDraw или ImageFont должен быть аттрибут textsize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш объект называется `image_draw`, значит, нужно так:

```
text_width, text_height = image_draw.textsize(reply_text, font=font)
```

Но с версии Pillow 10.0.0 metod `.textsize()` уже не существует, он был удален, так как его нужно заменить методами `.textbbox()`, `.textlength()` and `.multiline_textbbox()`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textsize'

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Просто установил версию 9.5.0 :)

Comment: @Quvi, не стоит, я рад, что вы с этим справились.